# Calculate next date from a given date in perl

Tags: perl

How to calculate next date from a given date in perl.

Ex. if given date is 2010-12-31 then 
it should return 2011-01-01/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern  => '%Y-%m-%d',
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('2010-12-31');
$dt->add( days => 1 );
say $format->format_datetime($dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date::Calc has a routine for doing this plus many more date calculating routines

you want to use the Add_Delta_Days function from Date::Calc